# Internal server error after uninstalling package nuget

Tags: c#, iis, nuget, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm creating a website with Umbraco 7, I installed the package FontAwesome Icons Dropdown with nuget command line

```
Install-Package FontAwesomeIconsDropdown
```

I noticed that is was the wrong package so I decided to remove it using:

```
Uninstall-Package FontAwesomeIconsDropdown
```

After I uninstalled the package I recieved a 500.19 error on the front end of the website, the backend is working fine.

some details about the error:
[image]

I think there is something wrong with the references but I can't find it, al already tried reinstalling ImageProcessor and deleting the line in the config file but both didn't do the trick.

Comment: Do you use some form of version control? Restore the project file, config file and package.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when we uninstall a package it does not uninstall every single file from the application. Some of the references still exists.

So, you can check the bin folder if there are any Dlls left. If yes, then delete them.

You can check any folders created with this package. If you using git or any other version control system then you can check the changed and the newly added files in order to make sure there are no more files left related to the package you install/uninstall.

Hope it helps!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a duplicate entry in the `<modules>` section of your `Web.config` file. This could happen if you have installed/removed packages and it somehow failed to detect the "old" line and then adds in another one during the NuGet install.

Could you make sure there is only one `<add name="ImageProcessorModule" .../>` entry in both the `<modules>` and the `<httpModules>` section of your `web.config` file?